# How to use multiple parsers for a single file type with prettier?

Tags: javascript, formatting, prettier

I want to use the [@prettier/plugin-php](https://github.com/prettier/plugin-php) to format my PHP code. Unfortunately it completely ignores any HTML in the PHP file, due to [concerns from the developers](https://github.com/prettier/plugin-php/issues/845). Those concerns don't apply on my project though, so I would like to also run the HTML parser on `*.php` files.

I have tried adding the following options to my prettier config:

```json
"overrides": [
    {
        "files": "*.php",
        "options": {
            "parser": "html"
        }
    }
]
```

This works perfectly for my HTML code, but unfortunately it now completely ignores the PHP code. Is there any way to use both parsers on `*.php` files?